# arcpy.ListDatasets will not read CAD files as datasets

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cad, list

I am essentially running [this script](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/cad/using-python-to-load-cad-data.htm) but for my own data.  The problem I am having is that the ListDatasets command is not recognizing the CAD .dwg files as datasets (as it should). It returns a 'None' after the arcpy.ListDatasets.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

(modules loaded earlier in script, print statements added for debugging purposes)

```
    arcpy.env.workspace = ("C:\\SY\\projects\\CGI\\test\\script_test\\CAD\\"+ FC)
    print arcpy.env.workspace
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    vTab = arcpy.ValueTable()
    arcpy.ListDatasets("W*.dwg")
    print arcpy.ListDatasets("W*.dwg")
    for fd in arcpy.ListDatasets("W*.dwg"):
        print 'Adding: ', fd
        layername = fd + "_Layer"
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fd + "/Polyline", layername, "\"Layer\" = 'C-DD-ALIGN' ")
        vTab.addRow(layername)
    arcpy.Merge_management(vTab, r"C:\SY\projects\CGI\test\script_test\sratch.gdb\test")
```

And here are the results I get

```
    C:\SY\projects\CGI\test\script_test\CAD\W_040 
    >>> None
    >>> ArcPy ERRORS:


     Done
```

Comment: What is `FC` in your first line?  Is that a valid folder name e.g. `C:\SY\projects\CGI\test\script_test\CAD\FolderName`?

Comment: Your code above works for me, so I'm guessing it's not finding any `DWG` files in that folder or it wasn't supported at 10.1.

Comment: The FC is part of a larger loop. It's purpose is to iterate through all of the DWG's in a folder.  However, it doesn't seem to be working properly.  When I delete the FC the script runs just fine.  Refer to @Midavalo 's post below.

Comment: Does the `FC` refer to a folder or a file?  A dataset is a container of feature classes (etc.), so to list datasets you'd need to look at a folder or geodatabase to find those datasets.  To find a CAD dataset your path needs to be a folder, not a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine for me - it looks like `arcpy.ListDatasets()` *does* in fact support CAD files, although not when using the `"CAD"` keyword (which you have excluded anyway).

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = (r"D:\GIS\SE\Cad")

# Without "CAD" keyword
print "No keyword"
print arcpy.ListDatasets("m*.dwg")

# With "CAD" keyword
print "CAD keyword"
print arcpy.ListDatasets("m*.dwg", "CAD")
```

Which outputs:

```
No keyword
[u'Midavalo.DWG', u'midavalo1.DWG']
CAD keyword
[]
```

I suspect the issue may be in your `arcpy.env.workspace` path.  Check that the path created by

```
"C:\SY\projects\CGI\test\script_test\CAD\"+ FC
```

is actually a valid path containing DWG files.  Also check they are `DWG` and not `DXF` files (otherwise you'd need to use `arcpy.ListDatasets("W*.DXF")` instead)

Comment: Yup, the '+ FC' is a variable in the loop and doesn't seem to be working properly. When I delete that piece it runs no problem.

Comment: IMO `os.path.join()` is a better choice for building file path strings.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `walk` in the [Data Access module](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm) lists `CadDrawing` as a valid data type to filter the results. You should be able to incorporate it into your script to replace `for fd in arcpy.ListDatasets("W*.dwg"):`